# Swift Change value of Coredata, not create new

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am new and dont understand to any objC, and there is no swift tut.

I am doing app for week planing, i have button, that add me to every day 
-name
-codeName
-Task01
.
.
-Task10

but if i want to edit one specific day, with another button, i always delete rest of the days, resp. i create new entity with a lot of nils and only the one day is full of information. here is my ghetto solution but it's not working right, it's working a few times, then it said it has about 512 searchResults.count and start lagging and dont work...

Please help me, how to change value of specific Attributes and dont create new entity

Here is my code for edit tuesday( rest of the week is same as monday, but its long code, so here is only code with monday and tuesday):

```
func getAndPrintData () {

    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Workout> = Workout.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let searchResults = try getContext().fetch(fetchRequest)
        print ("num of results = \(searchResults.count)")
        for works in searchResults as [NSManagedObject] {


            if let moc = managedObjectContext {
                let workout = Workout(context: moc)

                workout.mondayNameCD = works.value(forKey: "mondayNameCD") as! String?
                workout.mondayCodeNameCD = works.value(forKey: "mondayCodeNameCD") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask01 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks01") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask02 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks02") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask03 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks03") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask04 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks04") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask05 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks05") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask06 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks06") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask07 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks07") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask08 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks08") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask09 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks09") as! String?
                workout.mondayTask10 = works.value(forKey: "mondayTaks10") as! String?
                workout.tuesdayNameCD = DayName.text!
                workout.tuesdayCodeNameCD = CodeNameTextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayFocusCD = IconImageTextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask01 = Task01TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask02 = Task02TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask03 = Task03TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask04 = Task04TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask05 = Task05TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask06 = Task06TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask07 = Task07TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask08 = Task08TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask09 = Task09TextField.text!
                workout.tuesdayTask10 = Task10TextField.text!
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
    saveToCoreData() {
        self.navigationController!.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}

func saveToCoreData(completion: @escaping ()->Void){
    managedObjectContext!.perform {
        do {
            try self.managedObjectContext?.save()
            completion()
            print("Product saved to CoreData")
        } catch let error {
            print("Could not save Product to CoreData: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? {
    return (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, you already have a managed object `works`. Just update the values on it instead of creating a new `Workout`.